# how to count filled rows with specific row name - my sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

What I want to do is count all my filled rows of specific row name I select, let me give you an example:

Its like I have a table with 6 columns; the very first column is email - and the rest column are slot1, slot2, slot3, slot4, slot5.

Now what I want to have is a function that - when I select a specific email address - it returns how many slots are filled under that email address - just like when we use this command:

```
$t = select * from tabnlename where email=something 
mysql_fetch_array($t)
echo $t['slot1'] . $t['slot1'] and on and on ...
```

I want a function that counts how many slots are filled where `email = mychoiceemail`.

Let me give you some more details take a look at my sql table

```
supemail           slot1          slot2         slot3           slot4         slot5
opera@gmail.com   somedata       somedata       somedata        somedata       somedata
kaku@gmail.com     somedata                    somedata         somedata
nashu@gmail.com                  somedata
```

now what i want is when i select opera@gmail.com the function should return 5 as it has all 5 columns filled ! when i select kaku@gmail.com it should return 3 as it has 3 slots filled and when i select nashu@gmail.com it should return 1 only as it has only 1 slot filled !

Comment: what does your table structure/schema and query look like?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired output.

Comment: when you say "select * from tablename", could you please specify what columns are actually included as *?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [mysqli_query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php), there are plenty of examples there.

Your query could look something like:

```
select Count(*)
from MyTable
where email = $something
```

Comment: it is showing me 5 that is indeed correct but no matter if the field of the row is filled or not i just want filled rows to be counted !

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php

```
<?php

$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password");
mysql_select_db("database", $link);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1 where email='stuff@email.com'", $link);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

echo "$num_rows Rows\n";

?>
```

Comment: i posted that before you posted the needed details to your question...  if someone doesn't answer it i'll update my response to what you need after i get some work done really quick.

Comment: no one replying i updated my question please now see and answer thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

if i understand good , maybe u look for something like that
the sql will be yours and try this code bellow

```
        if ($t['slot1'] == "" ) {$s1 = $t['slot1'] ;}
           else {$s1notnull =$t['slot1'] ; }
        if ($t['slot2'] == "" ) {$s2 = $t['slot2'] ;}
           else {$s2notnull =$t['slot2'] ; }
        if ($t['slot3'] == "" ) {$s3 = $t['slot3'] ;}
           else {$s3notnull =$t['slot3'] ; }
        if ($t['slot4'] == "" ) {$s4 = $t['slot4'] ;}
           else {$s4notnull =$t['slot4'] ; }
        if ($t['slot5'] == "" ) {$s5 = $t['slot5'] ;}
           else {$s5notnull =$t['slot5'] ; }

        $array_empty = array($s1, $s2, $s3, $s4, $s5);
      $how_is_empty = count($array_empty);
```

hope it helps
EDIT .

```
         select email,slot1 as s1, slot2 as s2, slot3 as s3, slot4 as s4, slot5 as s5, (count(s1+s2+s3+s4+s5)) from tabnlename where email=something
```

Comment: exactly that is absolutely correct !!  but there is no way to find it out by sql query in php ?

Comment: There is no way in sql to do this ?

Comment: edited look up, u mean something like that ? if its empty one slot it will not be counted

Comment: no dear ! i have table that consist of more than 5000 entries so i want a more simpler function !

Comment: @user1663780 then try to modify this function, do some work yourself, and if you have a **real** problem, start a new question and we'll try to be nice to you